# Why does clearance increase after phenytoin overdose?

Tags: drugs, pharmacology

I am finding it hard to envision how an overdose of phenytoin ultimately leads to an increase of the clearance of phenytoin after the enzymes that metabolize phenytoin stop getting saturated.

I know it has to do with zero order and first order kinetics, but I just can't put it in perspective.

Would appreciate if someone could help out.

Comment: Isn't it suppose to decrease? Could please provide me with your reference, I have an answer but seems contradictory to your findings hence I wish to see reference before posting the answer.

Comment: Okay it's been a while decided to post, perhaps we  get more insight from the community

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. Sorry I only remember during which class I read this, but cannot remember where exactly anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> Phenytoin is primarily eliminated by hepatic metabolism (>95%).
>   Hepatic metabolism is mainly via the CYP2C9 enzyme system with a
>   smaller amount metabolized by CYP2C19. About 5% of a phenytoin dose is
>   recovered in the urine as unchanged drug. Phenytoin follows
>   **Michaelis-Menten** or **saturable pharmacokinetics**.

This is the type of nonlinear pharmacokinetics that occurs when the number of drug molecules overwhelms or saturates the enzyme’s ability to metabolize the drug. When this occurs, steady-state drug serum concentrations increase in a disproportionate manner after a dosage increase:

[image: mentelis equation s]

In this case the rate of drug removal is described by the classic Michaelis-Menten relationship that is used for all enzyme systems: rate of metabolism =$\ce{(Vmax ⋅ C) / (Km + C)}$, where Vmax is the maximum rate of metabolism in mg/d, C is the phenytoin concentration in mg/L, $\ce{Km}$ is the substrate concentration in mg/L, and where the rate of metabolism = $\ce{Vmax /2}$.

The clinical implication of Michaelis-Menten pharmacokinetics is that the clearance of phenytoin is not a constant as it is with linear pharmacokinetics, but is concentration- or dose-dependent. As the dose or concentration of phenytoin increases, the clearance rate (Cl) decreases as the enzyme approaches saturable conditions: $\ce{Cl = Vmax / (Km + C)}$. This is the reason **concentrations increase disproportionately** after a phenytoin dosage increase.

However, since clearance is dose or concentration-dependent, half-life also changes with phenytoin dosage or concentration changes. As doses or concentrations increase for a drug that follows Michaelis-Menten pharmacokinetics, clearance decreases and half-life becomes longer for the drug.

> For drugs such as phenytoin with a low hepatic extraction ratio
>   (≤30%), the numeric value of liver blood flow is much greater than the
>   product of unbound fraction of drug in the blood and the intrinsic
>   clearance of the compound (LBF >> fB)
>
> Plasma protein binding
>   displacement drug interactions cause major pharmacokinetic alterations
>   but are not clinically significant because the pharmacologic effect of
>   the drug does not change.

Because the clearance of the drug is

> **dependent on the fraction of unbound drug** in the blood and intrinsic clearance for a low hepatic extraction ratio agent, a
>   decrease in plasma protein binding and increase in unbound fraction
>   will increase clearance.

Currently there is no substantive evidence of phenytoin auto-inducing its own metabolism (the theory of phenytoin displacing itself from plasma proteins really isn’t convincing at all but perhaps in a drug interaction with a drug which is predominantly plasma bound). The reason being that the [information regarding phenytoin auto-induction is sparse and conflicting](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/9485556/). The results of this study aren’t convincing enough when taken in perspective of its ability to auto-induce itself after an overdose.

**References**

- Applied Clinical Pharmacokinetics: A. Bauer, Phenytoin: Basic Clinical Pharmacokinetic Parameters

Comment: Does this solve your question?